# spawn UNKNOWN Error when debug php on VS Code using xDebug 3

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp, xdebug-3

I have installed xDebug extension on VS Code with xampp (php) installed on another computer on the local network.

On my computer I have mapped a network drive (w) that points to \ip_of_xampp_computer\d$\xampp.

I have configured the following values:

```
 "php.debug.executablePath": "W:\\php\\ext\\php_xdebug.dll",
 "php.validate.executablePath": "w:\\php\\php.exe",
```

On the xampp computer I have copied php_xdebug.dll to D:\xampp\php\ext and I have added the following entries in php.ini (as indicated in the installation wizard):

```
zend_extension = xdebug
[xDebug]
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

When I try to debug a simple program It keeps trying and then I get the error message **spawn UNKNOUWN**:

[image]

launch.json file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9003
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 0,
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
        ],
        "env": {
            "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
            "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
            "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
            "-S",
            "localhost:0"
        ],
        "program": "",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "port": 9003,
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
            "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
            "action": "openExternally"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Thank you.?